# List view not getting rebuild properly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this comment section in my application.

 User can like a comment.
Whenever a comment is added, I call the database to get the latest comment and rebuild the class.

 But as shown below When a new comment is added, it retains the state of the previous comment

[image: demo]

as seen above when a not liked comment is added it is having state of previous comment

Below is the given code

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    getComments();
   
    super.initState();
  }

  getComments() async {
    try {
      List<Comment> commentList =
          await Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false)
              .postComments(widget.postid);

      setState(() {
        data = commentList;

        });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        data = 'error';
      });
      // throw ('e');
    }
  }

  dynamic data;


  addComment(BuildContext context) async {
    String commentData = _textEditingController.text.trim();
    if (commentData.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        showShimmer = true;

        _textEditingController.clear();
      });
      bool result = await Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false)
          .addMessageToPost(widget.postid, true, commentData);

      if (result) {
        getComments();
      }
    }
  }

  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: settingsAppBar(context, 'Comments'),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          showShimmer
              ? Shimmer.fromColors(
                  baseColor: Colors.grey[200]!,
                  highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
                  child: ShimmerWidget())
              : Container(),
          Expanded(
            child: data == null
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : data == 'error'
                    ? Center(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  getComments();
                                },
                                child: Text('Retry')),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    : data.length >= 1
                        ? RefreshIndicator(
                              onRefresh: () async {
          setState(() {
            data = null;
          });
          getComments();
        },
                          child: ListView(
                              controller: _scrollController,
                              children: buidlCommentWidgets()),
                        )
                        : Text('No data'),
          ),
          SafeArea(...textfield)  ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buidlCommentWidgets() {

    List<Widget> commentWidgetList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      commentWidgetList.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 8.0),
        child: CommentListTile(
          comment: data[i],
          postUid: widget.postedUid,
        ),
      ));
    }
    return commentWidgetList;
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CommentListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const CommentListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.comment,
    required this.postUid,
    this.isReply = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Comment comment;
  final String postUid;
  final bool isReply;

  @override
  _CommentListTileState createState() => _CommentListTileState();
}

class _CommentListTileState extends State<CommentListTile> {
  late bool isLiked;
  late int likeCount;

  handleLike(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() {
      isLiked = !isLiked;
      likeCount = isLiked ? likeCount + 1 : likeCount - 1;
    });

    bool result = await Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false)
        .postActivity(
            PostActivityEnum.likeDislikeComment, widget.comment.commentId);

    if (!result) {
      setState(() {
        isLiked = !isLiked;
        likeCount = isLiked ? likeCount + 1 : likeCount - 1;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    isLiked = widget.comment.isLikedByViewer;
    likeCount = widget.comment.likesCount;

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
....ListTile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem in the flutter.

This happens due to the widget tree and the render tree difference, Identification of the widget by its own `Key` can be easier for the flutter to keep an update on both render and widget tree.

For an easy solution, you can pass a unique key to the `CommentListTile` widget while building the list and also while adding a new widget to the list.

```dart
  List<Widget> buidlCommentWidgets() {
    List<Widget> commentWidgetList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      commentWidgetList.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 8.0),
        child: CommentListTile(
          key: SOME_UNIQUE_KEY_HERE // Add Unique key here
          comment: data[i],
          postUid: widget.postedUid,
        ),
      ));
    }
    return commentWidgetList;
  }
```

It can be easy if you have some kind of `commentId`.

### EDIT: 27 Aug 2021

##### You definitely should use your `buildCommentWidgets()` method like this:

```dart
  List<Widget> buidlCommentWidgets() {
    return data.map((comment) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: CommentListTile(
          key: SOME_UNIQUE_KEY_HERE // Add Unique key here
          comment: comment,
          postUid: widget.postedUid,
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```